# Access multiple rows using search operation in servlet

Tags: java, database, servlets

How to get multiple rows data in servlet or JSP from database using search query?

EX: I want to search by `fname` (ABCD) using JSP or servlet from database. In database multiple rows available for  "ABCD" then how to get all rows and their data of "ABCD"?

Comment: Use an array/list of objects to accumulate the rows and send it to jsp with request or session.

Answer (score 0):

To see the data in servlet from database you have to run the the following command:
ResultSet 
This will retrieve the data in servlet but to see the table values in console :

```
rs=st.executeQuery("Select * from Tablename);
    while(rs.next()){
    System.out.println(rs.nextInt("columon1")
    System.out.println(rs.nextString("columon2")
    System.out.println(rs.nextString("columon3")
    }
```

Comment: No hard feelings, but this does not answer to the question